# Check checkboxes based on Array - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a unique checkbox modal window

```
<div class="tv-choices" style="display:none;"><!-- turned on via button-->
<div class="choices-title">TV</div>
<div class="choices-checkboxes">
    <div class="category_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="getf{038}" name="getfItem" value="Adult Animated">
        <label for="get{038}">Adult Animated</label>
    </div>

    <div class="category_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="getf{9FA}" name="getfItem" value="Anime">
        <label for="get{9FA}">Anime</label>
    </div>

    <div class="category_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="getf{821}" name="getfItem" value="Award Shows">
        <label for="get{821}">Award Shows</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
object_with_arrays['genreAry'+ary_Num]
```

Let's say Array `object_with_arrays[genreAry1]` has: *Adult Animated* and *Anime* but not *Award Shows*. **How would you now get those checkboxes to get checked via jQuery?**

Project story:
I have 9 generated buttons which create a Modal window on the fly, each modal window serves up a set of checkboxes. Since I'm using 1 modal window I have to clear out the pervious checkboxes. I found this code below which works, but I just can't seem to figure out how to re-populate the checkboxes with my Arrays

```
$('.tv-choices').find(':checked').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

Comment: Pay attention that your input `id`s and label `for` attributes don't match. Also, you should use `.prop('checked', false)` instead of removing the attribute.

Comment: Ah thanks yeah that also clears out my checkboxes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.modal').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
   var state = $.inArray(this.value, object_with_arrays['genreAry1'])!=-1;

   $(this).prop('checked', state);
});
```

Iterate over the checkboxes, and set the checked property based on wether or not the checkbox value exists in the array ?

Comment: `object_with_arrays` is a multidimensional array, so the `in` approach can't work unless it contains objects (and I guess that `object_with_arrays` in array of arrays of strings).

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo - I've changed it, but still not sure what `object_with_arrays` is, as it seems strange to name an array "object", but I'll assume it's an array of arrays then.

Comment: +1. BTW in the question he says "Let's say Array object_with_arrays[genreAry1] has: Adult Animated and Anime but not Award Shows", so I think that `object_with_arrays[genreAry1] = ['Adult Animated', 'Anime']`.

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo - But arrays can't have named keys, that makes it by definition an object. There are no such thing as associative arrays in javascript, but the code above should work regardless !

Comment: Thanks @adeneo that worked! :D I can read how it works too.. 1 last question, I put an alert inside of that function. And it kept on popping up, I had to check don't show alert popups. When would that function die or is it like a constant loop?

Comment: It loops over all the checkboxes, setting the checked property on each one individually, so the alert would stop when there are no more checkboxes left to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on attributes with jQuery. If you were only looking for one item, it would be like this:

```
$('.modal').find('input:checkbox[value="Anime"]').each(function() {
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

But since you want to check against a list of values, you can use `filter` with a callback:

```
var searchValues = object_with_arrays['genreAry'+ary_Num]; 
//e.g. searchValues == ["Anime", "Adult Animated"]

$('.modal').find('input:checkbox').filter(function() {
   return searchValues.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0;
}).each(function() {
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

If you also want to *uncheck* all the other checkboxes:

```
$('.modal').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
   var checked = searchValues.indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0;
   $(this).prop('checked', checked)
});
```

Comment: I could not get alerts to go up in either line http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/DjDtW/

Comment: @Leon - There were some problems with your jsFiddle, but I've fixed them: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/DjDtW/2/ You didn't have jQuery loaded, and you had some variables (`reg.the_Num` and `object_with_arrays`) that weren't defined in your fiddle. You also needed to wrap the HTML in an element with class `modal`. These were probably set up in your page, but they weren't defined in the sample. Also, this looks like an older version of my code. Anyway, it's all fixed now and works fine! Check my version.

Comment: @Leon - The shorter version (my last code block above) works fine too: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/DjDtW/3/